# Designing a resize function for a queue

Tags: c, api-design, software-design, memory-reallocation

I'm currently trying to design a public API for a queue data structure and resize function to change its size. My first intention was to do it in the following way:

```
typedef struct queue queue;

/**
 * Resizes a given queue.
 *
 * Changes the size of the queue passed as a parameter. 
 * The content of the resized queue prior to the lesser
 * of new and old sizes is left unchanged. 
 *
 * Returns:
 *  0 - on success
 * -1 - on error and the content of the original queue is left unchanged
 */
int queue_resize(queue * queue_ptr, size_t new_size);
```

The problem is I read the contract to `realloc` and it was the following:

> The `realloc` function  returns  a  pointer  to  the  new object  (which
>   may  have  the  same value  as  a  pointer  to  the  old  object),  or
>   a  null  pointer  if  the  new  object  could  not  be allocated.

Is it a common approach for reallocation functions to return a new object and reclaim the old one? So in such a case I should have redesigned the `int queue_resize(queue *queue_ptr, size_t);` to make `queue * queue_resize(queue *queue_ptr, size_t);` with the corresponding contract changes.

Comment: Because `realloc` can return a different memory address, you must pass the function a double pointer; otherwise he caller cannot observe the changed pointer: `queue **queue_ptr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`realloc` must be able to move the allocated space to a different address for it to be able to work. Imagine the memory directly after the currently allocated memory was already in use. Without relocation you could not create a contiguous sequence.

Typically your queue will look something like this

```
typedef struct queue {
  some_type* data_member;
  size_t size;
  size_t capacity;
  // .. perhaps more
} queue;
```

So when you have a `queue_resize` function you can just pass a `queue*` and the new size. What you pass to `realloc` is not the `queue*` but its `data_member`. Since you already have a pointer to the `queue` object, you can just update the pointer of `data_member` if `realloc` chooses to change it.

In this case returning a new `queue*` object is not necessary, because the memory footprint of `queue` never changes. Nor do you have to pass a `queue**` or anything of the sort.

Comment: I don't really understand the point of `queue **`. The struct can points to a different underlying buffer gotten after the reallocation. I mean like `struct queue{ void *memory; size_t size; //other fields}`. So we just replace the `void* memory`. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @St.Antario See my addendum, that pretty much does what you suggest. You basically need some wrapper type with a pointer around your actual implementation.

Comment: So if you already have `void* memory` member you can directly realloc that one and update the pointer in your `queue` object.

Comment: So there is a trade off between performance and avoiding queue relocation.

Comment: If I think about it, not really. Your queue HAS to have a memory buffer pointer at any rate. I overlooked that. Allow me to edit the answer.

Comment: @St.Antario There you go.

Answer (score 2):

Previous answers/comments do not address what to do with the data. Consider what is done in Java when the Java run-time discovers that the Array needs to be bigger. E.g. you try to append an element to an already full Array.

- a new Array is allocated with the desired size; this includes setting up the meta data
- a lock has to be set so the old Array doesn't change
- all data is copied from the existing Array to the new Array; includes updating meta data; note that both Arrays need to exist at the same time for this
- the original Array is removed (not sure of the right word here.)
- the lock is removed
- If you just fiddle with pointers, you will loose the data.
- You can easily copy the data using standard methods such as Add() and Remove()